# Has anyone gotten a .jar to run on google app engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, hosting

I don't really want to push my whole project, as I don't update the server at all.

Google App Engine supports java, but is fairly complicated.

Just wondering if anyone has successfully been able te get a simple jar running on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean just a simple JAR with a main method, that won't work. Your application has to be a web service that responds to requests.

If you want to just be running random code on a host in the cloud, you should take a look at the [free tier](http://aws.amazon.com/free/) of [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I know of to start getting code working on GAE for Java is [Gaelyk](http://gaelyk.appspot.com/). If you unzip the template project, you can deploy it to GAE immediately. You can write simple servlets (as Groovlets) in Groovy, or add Java Servlets to the web.xml. Groovy code can make calls to Java transparently (and vice versa, as Groovy produces and consumes Java objects).

As Adrian notes, GAE is a platform for deploying web applications and services. If your program is not accessible as a web application or service, I'm curious what benefit there is to using a cloud provider.